# Refreshing the content of TabView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Ok I am trying to refresh the tab content of each of my tabs after a web call has been made, and I have tried soo many different methods to do this that I have lost count. Could someone please tell me how this is possible?

The web call just calls JSON from a server and uses it to update the content of the tabs. For testing purposes I have a button set up inside my settings class. Settings class is a view within the home tab which has a button called refresh. When clicked this takes JSON stored on the device which is different to the one called from the web call on application start up. This saves me having to change the JSON on the server.

I will take you through some of the techniques I have tried and would be grateful if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong.

I tried making an instance of the class and calling the refresh method like this

```
DashboardVC *db = [[DashboardVC alloc] init];
[db refreshMe];
```

The refresh method in dashboard class is this

```
-(void) refreshMe
{     
     [self loadView];
     [self viewDidLoad];
}
```

However no luck. This method will work if I call it inside the Dashboard class, but wont work if I call it from another class. I think it is become I am instantiating a new class and calling refresh on that. So I dropped that technique and moved onto the next method

This loops through all the tabBars and changes the tabTitles without any issues, so it I know it is definitely looping through the ViewControllers properly.

I also tried every varient of the view methods like ViewDidAppear, viewWillAppear etc, no luck.

I also tried accessing the refreshMe method I made in the dashBoard class through the tabController like this

```
[[[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] refreshMe];
```

But again no luck, this just causes my application to crash.

I read through this guide

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerPGforiOSLegacy/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html

on the apple website but it doesn't seem to cover how to refresh individual tab content.

All I want is to have each individual tab refresh its content after the web call is made, and have spent ages trying to figure this out, but nothing is working.

So would be very grateful if someone could show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanx in advance....

EDIT:

Expand on what I have tried

After discussion with Michael I realised you should never call loadView as against Apple guidelines. So I removed any references to LoadView. I have now placed a method in all the main ViewControllers called RefreshMe which sets up the views, images texts etc in the class. And this method is placed inside the ViewDidLoad. Now I want to be able to call these methods after a web call has taken place, so effectively refreshing the application.

My viewDidLoad now looks like this in all my the main classes.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     [self refreshMe];
}
```

And then the refreshMe method contains the code which sets up the screen.

The JSON data pulled from the web call will set up the content of each of the 5 tabs, so need them all to be refreshed after web call.

I tried looping through the viewControllers and calling viewDidLoad, which should in turn call the refreshMe method which sets up the class, however nothing happens. Code I used was this

```
NSArray * tabBarViewControllers = [self.tabBarController viewControllers];

for(UIViewController * viewController in tabBarViewControllers)
{
    [viewController viewDidLoad];
}
```

For the time being I have also included

```
NSLog(@"Method called");
```

in the viewDidLoad of each class to test if it is being called. However the message is only being printed out when I first load the application or if I re-enter the application. This method should be called after I click the refresh button in the settings screen but it isn't and I have no idea why.

Anyone have any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question and your comments, it sounds like there are at least two problems:

1. You're having trouble accessing the view controllers managed by your app's tab bar controller.
2. You seem to be working against the normal operation of your view controllers.

The first part should be straightforward to sort out. If you have a pointer to an object, you can send messages to that object. If the corresponding method doesn't execute, then either the pointer doesn't point where you think it does or the object doesn't have the method that you think it does. Let's look at your code:

```
NSArray * tabBarViewControllers = [self.tabBarController viewControllers];

for(UIViewController * viewController in tabBarViewControllers)
{
    [viewController viewDidLoad];
}
```

This code is supposed to call `-viewDidLoad` on each of the view controllers managed by some tab bar controller. Leaving aside the wisdom of doing that for a moment, we can say that this code should work as expected *if* `self.tabBarController` points to the object that you think it does. You don't say where this code exists in your app -- is it part of your app delegate, part of one of the view controllers managed by the tab bar controller in question, or somewhere else? Use the debugger to step through the code. After the first line, does `tabBarViewControllers` contain an array of view controllers? Is the number of view controllers correct, and are they of the expected types? If the `-viewDidLoad` methods for your view controllers aren't being called, it's a good bet that the answer is "no," so figure out why `self.tabBarController` isn't what you think.

Now, it's definitely worth pointing out (as Michael did) that you shouldn't be calling `-viewDidLoad` in the first place. The view controller will send that method to itself after it has created its view (either loaded it from a .xib/storyboard file or created it programmatically). If you call `-viewDidLoad` yourself, it'll either run before the view has been created or it'll run a second time, and neither of those is helpful.

Also, it doesn't make much sense to try to "refresh" each view controller's view preemptively.  If your app is retrieving some data from a web service (or anywhere else), it should use the resulting data to update its model, i.e. the data objects that the app manages. When a view controller is selected, the tab bar controller will present its view and the view controller's `-viewWillAppear` method will be called just before the view is displayed. Use that method to grab the data you need from the model and update the view. Doing it this way, you know that:

- the view controller's view will have already been created
- the data displayed in the view will be up to date, even if one of the other view controllers modified the data
- you'll never spend time updating views that the user may never look at

Similarly, if the user can make any changes to the displayed data, you should ensure that you update the model either when the changes are made or else in your view controller's `-viewWillDisappear` method so that the next view controller will have correct data to work with.

Comment: The tabBarController is set up in the appDelegate. I checked the self.tabBarController, it is def getting 5 viewControllers. I can get a refresh working with viewWillAppear, but my home tab has animations in it, which means every time the user selects this tab, the animation will reset and that will look weird. I only want the animation to run the first time they open the app again, or when the web call is made again. I will have it called periodically.

Comment: Also I understand your point about pre-emptive loading, that is a bit odd. Will switch to the ViewDidAppear, but I would just like to prevent the animations running every time they select the tab

Comment: You're in control -- don't run the animations if you don't want them. Maybe you set a flag in your view controller's initialization method  that says "should run animations", and then you clear the flag after they run once. They shouldn't run again unless you kill and restart the app (or you otherwise destroy and recreate your view controller for some reason). Your animation issue doesn't need to be tied up with your refresh issue.

Comment: That actually makes more sense. Will give that a shot, thanks a lot for your help and your detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of refreshing your view controllers when updating your tab bar ordering, why not simply refresh your views right before they will appear by implementing your subclassed UIViewController's [`viewWillAppear:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear%3a) method?

What this means is that each time your view is about to appear, you can update the view for new & updated content.

Comment: But that means that tabs will refresh their view everytime I click them, is that not an inefficient way of doing it?

Comment: Also the other problem with this is, my home screen has several animations in it, which means every time I clicked the homescreen tab the animation will reset again which will look odd

Comment: It *may* be, depending on what kind of data or information you're displaying in your view (but since I'm not looking at your view, I can't really comment specifically).  The "refresh" method I told you about before ([in your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648696/iphone-refreshing-tabcontroller-and-content)) should work, provided you implement your refresh method correctly.  You shouldn't call `viewDidLoad` or `loadView` on a view controller directly, and especially ones that are already loaded (crash city).

Comment: I tried that though and no luck. If I make an instance of the class and call refresh on it, nothing happens. It just calls refresh on the instance of the class I have created, not the one in place. What should I do instead of loadView and viewDidLoad?

Comment: Adam... don't create a new instance of your view controllers.  They already exist in the tab bar controller and you're just reordering them.  Enumerate (i.e. loop through) the array of view controllers that are associated with the tab bar controllers and call refresh on that.  Makes sense?

Comment: But I did that if you look at the code I presented, the for loop, I looped through the ViewControllers in the tab bar controller and did the loadView and viewDidLoad and nothing happened. And I tried calling the refresh method within the DashBoard class as well by selecting the DashBoard class through the TabBarContorller and that just caused by app to crash. How else am I meant to call refresh? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Look at this code I linked here](http://pastebin.com/1qXRG7eL).  If you implement a "`refreshMe`" method in each of your view controllers, a "`refreshMe`" call will be made as the loop happens.  The reason you weren't seeing an update in your "DashBoard" was because you were creating a brand new Dashboard instance and refreshing on that, instead of the one that the tab bar controller is keeping track of.

Comment: I added the refreshMe method into the the viewControllers for each tab. Added it both in the interface and the implementation so as can be called from other classes. Yet when I call use the code   [viewController refreshMe]; It says No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'refreshMe' Any idea why? Does it matter that my tabController sets up a navigation Controller inside the tab Controller?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11429/discussion-between-michael-dautermann-and-adamm)